# Symfony5 Custom Validator in FormType - Validate password field when check box is on

Tags: symfony, symfony5

I would like to validate a input password field in a form based in the value of checkbox.  If the value is TRUE the password fields should be NOTBlank and Equal first to second.  This what i have so far:

```
namespace App\Form;

use App\Entity\User;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\Email;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\NotBlank;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\Length;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\Callback;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Context\ExecutionContextInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\CheckboxType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\PasswordType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\RepeatedType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\EmailType;


class UsuarioFormType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
        ->add('nombre',null,[
            'required'   => true,
            'constraints'=> [
                new NotBlank([
                    'message' => 'Escriba el nombre por favor',
                ]),
            ]
        ])
        ->add('apellido',null,[
            'required'   => true,
            'constraints'=> [
                new NotBlank([
                    'message' => 'Escriba el apellido por favor',
                ]),
            ]
        ])
        ->add('user_name',null,[
            'required'   => true,
            'empty_data' => '',
            'constraints'=> [
                new NotBlank([
                    'message' => 'Escriba el nombre de usuario por favor',
                ]),
            ]
        ])
        ->add('active', CheckboxType::class, [
            'required' => false
        ])
        ->add('email',EmailType::class,[
            'constraints' => [
                new Email([
                    'mode'=> 'html5',
                    'message' => 'El correo electrónico {{ value }} no es un correo electrónico válido',
                ]),
            ]
        ])        
        ->add('plainPassword', RepeatedType::class, [
            'type' => PasswordType::class,
            'invalid_message' => 'Los campos de contraseña deben ser iguales',
            'mapped' => false,
            'required'   => false,
            'constraints' => [
                new Length([
                    'min' => 6,
                    'minMessage' => 'Your password should be at least {{ limit }} characters',
                    // max length allowed by Symfony for security reasons
                    'max' => 4096,
                ]),
            ],
        ]);
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => User::class,
            'constraints' => [
                new Callback([$this, 'validate']),
            ],
        ]);
    }
    public function validate($data, ExecutionContextInterface $context): void
    {
        if ($data['chk_passUpdate']){
            if (trim($data['plainPassword']['first']) == '' ) {
                $context->buildViolation('El campo de contraseña no puede estar en blanco')
                ->atPath('plainPassword')
                ->addViolation();
            }
            if ($data['plainPassword']['first'] != $data['plainPassword']['second'] ) {
                $context->buildViolation('Los campos de contraseña deben ser iguales')
                ->atPath('plainPassword')
                ->addViolation();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This code throw a Exception:

*Argument 1 passed to App\Form\UsuarioFormType::validate() must be of the type array, object given, called in C:\Csi\CsiWorkspace\SynfonyTest\SymfonyTest\vendor\symfony\validator\Constraints\CallbackValidator.php on line 46*

Comment: Are you sure that the method signature is exactly the one you posted? The error should be generated only if an “array” type-hint is present on first parameter. Anyway, the first parameter here should be an instance of User, the matching of the repeated field is already ensured by the RepeatedType and the non emptiness should be checked via a NotBlank constraint.

Comment: Seems that in this part "new Callback([$this, 'validate'])," the var $this refer to the object $user (user entity).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a week i found the best solution is to use validation groups.

So my code will be like this:

```
namespace App\Form;

use App\Entity\User;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\Email;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\NotBlank;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\Length;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\Callback;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Context\ExecutionContextInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\CheckboxType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\PasswordType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\RepeatedType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\EmailType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormInterface;


class UsuarioFormType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
        ->add('nombre',null,[
            'required'   => true,
            'constraints'=> [
                new NotBlank([
                    'message' => 'Escriba el nombre por favor',
                ]),
            ]
        ])
        ->add('apellido',null,[
            'required'   => true,
            'constraints'=> [
                new NotBlank([
                    'message' => 'Escriba el apellido por favor',
                ]),
            ]
        ])
        ->add('user_name',null,[
            'required'   => true,
            'empty_data' => '',
            'constraints'=> [
                new NotBlank([
                    'message' => 'Escriba el nombre de usuario por favor',
                ]),
            ]
        ])
        ->add('active', CheckboxType::class, [
            'required' => false
        ])
        ->add('password_update', CheckboxType::class, [
            'required'  => false,
            'mapped'    => false
        ])
        ->add('email',EmailType::class,[
            'constraints' => [
                new Email([
                    'mode'=> 'html5',
                    'message' => 'El correo electrónico {{ value }} no es un correo electrónico válido',
                ]),
            ]
        ])        
        ->add('plainPassword', RepeatedType::class, [
            'type' => PasswordType::class,
            'invalid_message' => 'Los campos de contraseña deben ser iguales',
            'mapped' => false,
            'required'   => false,
            'constraints' => [
                new Length([
                    'min' => 6,
                    'minMessage' => 'Your password should be at least {{ limit }} characters',
                    // max length allowed by Symfony for security reasons
                    'max' => 4096,
                ]),
                new NotBlank([
                    'message' => 'Escriba su contraseña',
                    'groups' => 'password_update'
                ]),
            ],
        ]);
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => User::class,
            'validation_groups' => function(FormInterface $form){
                if ($form['password_update']->getData()){
                    return array('Default', 'password_update');
                }else{
                    return array('Default');
                }
            }

        ]);
    }

}
```

In that way, when the checkbox is on, the form will validate 2 groups (default and password_udpate). If its off only the default group will be validated.

Hope this help somebody some day.